# Basic Topology: "A" an open set, then B= A \{p} is an open set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is this demonstration right or am I missing something?

A an open set, p ∈ A, then B=A\{p} is an open set

Dem:

- x ∈ B
- $\varepsilon_{max} > 0 : B(x,\varepsilon_{max}) ⊂ B$
- $\delta$ = min{ d(p,x) , $\varepsilon_{max}$ }

⇒ B(x,$\delta$) ⊂ B , $\forall$  x ∈ B

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyVyd.jpg)

That's it, thanks.

Comment: What is the situation here? What is the topology? Are you in a metric space? I think you have all the right ideas but it is hard to know without a bit more detail.

Comment: Hint: In a metric space, a singleton set is closed

Comment: The proof is good

Comment: A-{x}= U{B(a,d(a,x)/2)| a is in A-{x}} is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that finite intersections of open sets are open. Note that $A \setminus \{x\}=A \cap \{x\}^c$. Thus $A \setminus \{x\}$ will be open if $\{x\}^c$ is open, i.e if $\{x\}$ is closed. If you're in a metric space, this is certainly the case.

Answer (score 0):

This demonstration is inadequate, since it assumes that topology $A$ is equiped with a metric (after all, you use $d(p,x)$).

Answer (score 0):

Without further knowledge (e.g. that we are in a metric space) this is certainly not true. As a simple example, if $X = \{a, b\}$ then we have the trivial topology $\tau = \{\emptyset, \{a, b\}\}$ where $\{a, b\} \setminus \{a\} = \{b\} \not\in \tau$.

Generally, it is sufficient that singleton sets are closed (see the answer by mb-); this is the case in [$\text{T}_1$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space). The trivial topology described above is not even a $\text{T}_0$ space; for a $\text{T}_0$ space which works as a counterexample try $\tau = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$.